TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest' and 'node', turborepo errors with jest
establishing monorepo environment using turborepo, vite, typescript and react.
I was migrated original app's code to monorepo apps folder blow but there are lot of error about jest code.
migrated code outputs error message they cannot find name 'describe', 'it', 'jest' and so on.
so, I add "types": ["jest", "node"] to config file but it outputs other errors.
// error message 
TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest' and 'node', 


// monorepo proejects
apps
ㄴmembers
  ㅏ ...
  ㅏpackage.json
  ㅏtsconfig.json
  ㄴvite.config.ts
node_modules
packages
  ㄴtypescript-config
     ㅏbase.json
     ㄴvite.json
.env
jest.config.cjs
jest.polyfills.cjs
package.json
tsconfig.json
turbo.json

// <root>/packages/typescript-config/vite.json
{
  ... 
  "types": ["jest", "node"],
}

// <root>/package.json
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.2.5",
    "ts-jest-mock-import-meta": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.6.3"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ]
}

// <root>/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json"
}

// apps/members/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/vite.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] },
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/@types", "src/mocks"]
}

// apps/members/package.json
{
   ...
   "jest": {
    "preset": "../../jest.config.js",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
    ]
  }
}


additionally apps/members/tsconfig.json outputs other errors
"Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'.
The file is in the program for the following reason:
Entry point of type library 'jest' specified in compilerOptions" and "node"
just run turbo run lint and turbo run dev without error
